# How can I check if a char * is empty?

Tags: c, string, pointers, char

How can I check if `char *name` is empty?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void store_stuff(char **name, int *age);
int main(void) {

    char *name;
    int age;

    store_stuff(&name, &age);

    printf("Name: %s\n", name);
    printf("Age: %d\n", age);

}

void store_stuff(char **name, int *age) {

    *age = 31;

    if (name == NULL) { // how can I check here if char name is empty?
        *name = "ERROR";
    }

}
```

Comment: What is "empty" ? Initialize it to `NULL` in the beginning and check `*name == NULL`. Yet it looks like XY-problem to me. This whole approach is going to give you troubles in the future.

Comment: strlen works by counting the number of characters up untill the null char '\0'

You could check to see if the first character is equal to '\0'

Comment: This Michigan University student still can't understand pointers...

Answer (score 7):

Pointers aren't "empty", they either point at valid data or invalid data. A controlled way to make them point at invalid data is to assign them to `NULL`. Thus the correct way to write the program would be:

```
char *name = NULL;
int age;
store_stuff(&name, &age);

...

void store_stuff(char **name, int *age) {
  if(*name == NULL)
  {
    // handle error
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: As a side-note, pointers with static storage duration are automatically initialized to NULL.

Comment: `NULL` is not a pointer to invalid data. The C standard does not say it points to anything at all, valid or invalid. It is merely a value that, when converted to a pointer type, compares unequal to a pointer to any object or function, but does compare equal to a null pointer. Hence it does not point to any object or function. And pointers are not limited to pointing to something or being a null pointer constant; they could also be invalid values.

Comment: Well... https://www.quora.com/What-does-a-null-pointer-point-to-if-it-does-not-point-to-anything-How-it-is-treated-internally

Answer (score 2):

*How can I check if char `*name` is empty ?* `name` is not initialized in `main()` function, First assign `NULL` to `name` like

```
char *name =  NULL; /* now its initialized */
```

**Case-1 :**

```
int main(void) {
    char *name =  NULL;
    store_stuff(&name, &age);
    /* code */
    return 0;
}
```

And then check `*name` content in the `store_stuff()` as

```
void store_stuff(char **name, int *age) {
    if (*name == NULL) { /* since name is double ptr here, *name means NULL in the main() if it is */
     /* error handling */
    }
 }
```

**Case-2 :** if `name` holds some data like `char *name = "Zoey";` in `main()` function.

```
int main(void) {
    char *name = "Zoey" ;
    store_stuff(&name, &age);
    /* code */
    return 0;
}
```

then below condition won't true & I hope this is what you want

```
void store_stuff(char **name, int *age) {
    if (*name == NULL) { /* now its not NULL as it holds some data */
     /* error handling */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems clear, but the code shown with it makes it less so:

```
if (name == NULL) { // how can I check here if char name is empty?
    *name = "ERROR";
}
```

This is undefined behavior. **If** `name` really is `NULL`, you can't dereference it, but that's what you do in the next line.

Of course, the way you call this function, it can never happen. You call it like this:

```
store_stuff(&name, &age);
```

and the `&` operator always evaluates to a valid, non-`NULL`, pointer.

---

In general, it's unclear what you mean by "empty". There's a special value `NULL` for pointers that means "this pointer doesn't point to anything". But that doesn't mean "empty", it still has a value: `NULL`.

In the context of *strings*, empty would have a well-defined meaning. As strings in C are defined as a sequence of characters that ends with a `\0` byte, an *empty* string has `\0` as the very first character. So, assuming `char *str` is a string, you can check for an empty string like

```
if (*str == 0)
```

or even shorter:

```
if (!*str)
```

Be aware this will lead to undefined behavior if `str` is `NULL` (doesn't point to **any** string). If you don't know anything about it and have to check it indeed points to a string and that string is non-empty, you could write something like

```
if (!str || !*str)
```

which is roughly equivalent to the `IsNullOrEmpty()` method on a .NET string ...

Comment: Felix he wanted probably name="ERROR" but his problem is completely different. He just does not know anything about the pointers and he needs a C book first.

Comment: I sometimes use `if(str) if(!*str)` to check if a string is empty, but even though str != NULL there is still no guarantee that it is dereferencable. (also not using {}s in if-conditions is bad practice and should very well generate warnings).